# Jquery 1.5.2 substitute for .on() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I's there any Jquery specialist to help me here?

I'm in a project that I need to use Jquery 1.5.2, and I need to use **.on()** function.

What's the way to make it work?

The code model is below:

```js
$(document).on('mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange fullscreenchange',function(){
        //some code
              alert("fulscreen change")
   });

function fullscreen() {
          alert("full");
       if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
        !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
       if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
         document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
       } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
         document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
       } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
         document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
       } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
         document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
       }
     } else {
       if (document.exitFullscreen) {
         document.exitFullscreen();
       } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
         document.msExitFullscreen();
       } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
         document.mozCancelFullScreen();
       } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
         document.webkitExitFullscreen();
       }
     }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='fullscreen()'>fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: use `live()` or `delegate()`

Comment: thanks!!! @PranavCBalan

Comment: It's a way! if you want you can answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** in older version

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). ( Taken from http://api.jquery.com/live/ )

```js
$('button').live('click', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `delegate`:

```
<button id="fullscreen">fullscreen</button>

jQuery(document).delegate('#fullscreen', 'click', function() {
    fullscreen();
});
```